# How do i call one Mutator/Setter from another in java?

Tags: java

```
package finalproject;




public class FinalProject 

{

 //------------------------------- Attributes --------------------------------

    public String name;
    public double cout;
    public int choice;
    public Double temp;
    public Double salary;
    public  Double salary2;
    public  Double salary3;  
    public Double share;
    public Double hdmf;
    public Double sss;
    public Double tax;
    public Double basicsalary;
    public Double netpay;

  //------------------------------- Constructor --------------------------------

 public FinalProject (){

    this.name="";
    this.cout=0.0;
    this.temp=0.0;
    this.choice = 0;
    this.basicsalary = 0.0;
    this.salary=0.0;
    this.salary2=salary;
    this.salary3=0.0;
    this.share=0.0;
    this.hdmf=0.0;
    this.sss=0.0;
    this.tax=0.0;   
    this.netpay = 0.0;
    }  

 //------------------------------- Setter --------------------------------



public void setName(String name){ 

    this.name=name;
}

public void setCout(Double salary){ 

    if (salary < 30000.00){
          System.out.print("\n ----------------- \n RESULT:"); 
       System.out.print("\nYour Position is Staff" + "\n");
    }

    else if (salary >= 30000.00 && salary <= 49999.00){
          System.out.print("\n ----------------- \n RESULT:"); 
        System.out.print("\nYour Position is Supervisor"+ "\n");
    }

    else if (salary >= 50000.00 && salary <= 79999.00){
          System.out.print("\n ----------------- \n RESULT:"); 
        System.out.print("\nYour Position is Manager"+ "\n");
    }

     else if (salary >= 80000.00 && salary <= 100000.00){
           System.out.print("\n ----------------- \n RESULT:"); 
        System.out.print("\nYour Position is Junior Officer"+ "\n");
    }

     else if (salary > 100001.00){
           System.out.print("\n ----------------- \n RESULT:"); 
        System.out.print("\nYour Position is Senior Officer"+ "\n");
    }
   // salary = cout;


}

public void setChoice(int choice){ 

    this.choice=choice;
}

public void setBasicsalary(Double basicsalary){

    this.basicsalary = basicsalary;
}

public void setNetpay(Double netpay){

    netpay = -this.salary - this.hdmf - this.salary3 - this.tax;
            this.netpay=netpay;
}


public void setSalary(Double salary){



    if(salary <= 8999.99 )
        {
            salary = 100.00;

        }

    else if(salary >= 9000 && salary <= 9999.99)
    {
        salary = 112.50;

    }

    else if(salary >= 10000 && salary <= 10999.99)
    {
        salary = 125.00;

    }

    else if(salary >= 11000 && salary <= 11999.99)
    {
        salary = 137.50;

    }

    else if(salary >= 12000 && salary <= 12999.99)
    {
        salary = 150.00;

    }

    else if(salary >= 13000 && salary <= 13999.99)
    {
        salary = 162.50;

    }

    else if(salary >= 14000 && salary <= 14999.99)
    {
        salary = 175.50;

    }

    else if(salary >= 15000 && salary <= 15999.99)
    {
        salary = 187.50;

    }

    else if(salary >= 16000 && salary <= 16999.99)
    {
        salary = 200.00;

    }

    else if(salary >= 17000 && salary <= 17999.99)
    {
        salary = 212.50;

    }

    else if(salary >= 18000 && salary <= 18999.99)
    {
        salary = 225.00;

    }

    else if(salary >= 19000 && salary <= 19999.99)
    {
        salary = 237.50;

    }

    else if(salary >= 20000 && salary <= 20999.99)
    {
        salary = 250.00;

    }

    else if(salary >= 21000 && salary <= 21999.99)
    {
        salary = 262.50;

    }

    else if(salary >= 22000 && salary <= 22999.99)
    {
        salary = 275.00;

    }

    else if(salary >= 23000 && salary <= 23999.99)
    {
        salary = 287.50;

    }

    else if(salary >= 24000 && salary <= 24999.99)
    {
        salary = 300.00;

    }

    else if(salary >= 25000 && salary <= 25999.99)
    {
        salary = 312.50;

    }

    else if(salary >= 26000 && salary <= 26999.99)
    {
        salary = 325.00;

    }

    else if(salary >= 27000 && salary <= 27999.99)
    {
        salary = 337.50;

    }

    else if(salary >= 28000 && salary <= 28999.99)
    {
        salary = 350.00;

    }

    else if(salary >= 29000 && salary <= 29999.99)
    {
        salary = 362.50;

    }

    else if(salary >= 30000 && salary <= 30999.99)
    {
        salary = 375.00;

    }

    else if(salary >= 31000 && salary <= 31999.99)
    {
        salary = 387.50;

    }

    else if(salary >= 32000 && salary <= 32999.99)
    {
        salary = 400.00;

    }

    else if(salary >= 33000 && salary <= 33999.99)
    {
        salary = 412.50;

    }

    else if(salary >= 34000 && salary <= 34999.99)
    {
        salary = 425.00;

    }

    else if(salary >= 35000)
    {
        salary = 437.50;

    }

    this.salary=salary;


}
public void setSalary2(Double salary2){

    this.salary2=salary2;
}

public void temp(Double temp){


    this.temp=temp;
}

public void setSalary3(Double salary3){


     if(this.salary3 < 30000){
       salary3 = salary3 * 0.05;
    }

    else if (this.salary3 >= 30000 && this.salary3 <= 49999){
       salary3 = salary3 * 0.07;
    }

    else if (this.salary3 >= 50000 && this.salary3 <= 79999){
        salary3 = salary3 * 0.08;
    }

     else if (this.salary3 >= 80000 && this.salary3 <= 100000){
         salary3 =salary3 * 0.1;
    }

     else if (this.salary3 > 100001){
        salary3 = salary3 * 0.15;
    }


    this.salary3=salary3;
}



public void setShare(Double share){

    this.share=share;
}

public void setTemp(Double temp){

    this.temp=temp;
}

public void setHdmf(Double hdmf){

    if(hdmf > 100){
            System.out.print("Prefered HDMF value has been entered" + "\n");

              this.hdmf = hdmf;

        }
        else if(hdmf == 0){
            System.out.print("Default has been chosen to deduct 100 HDMF" + "\n");
            salary2 = 100.00;
             this.hdmf = salary2;
        }

}

public void setSss(Double sss){

    this.sss = sss * 0.50;   
}

public void setTax(Double tax){

    this.tax = tax * 0.50;

}

//getter

public String getName(){

    return this.name;
}

public Double getCout(){

    return this.cout;
}

public int getChoice(){

    return this.choice;
}

public Double getBasicsalary(){

    return this.basicsalary;
}

public Double getNetpay(){

    return this.netpay;
}

public Double getSalary(){

    return this.salary;
}

public Double getTemp(){

    return this.temp;
}

public Double getSalary2(){ 

    return this.salary2;
}

public Double getSalary3(){

    return this.salary3;
}

public Double getShare(){

    return this.share;
}

public Double getHdmf(){


    return this.hdmf;
}

public Double getSss(){

    return this.sss;
}

public Double getTax(){

    return this.tax;
}






}
```

//------------------------------- Main Class --------------------------------

```
package finalproject;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class FinalProjectMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        FinalProject output1 = new FinalProject();//name
        FinalProject output2 = new FinalProject();//share
        FinalProject output3 = new FinalProject(); //hdmf //salary2
        FinalProject output4 = new FinalProject();//sss
        FinalProject output5 = new FinalProject();//position
        FinalProject output6 = new FinalProject();//tax
        FinalProject output7 = new FinalProject();//Basicsalary
        FinalProject output8 = new FinalProject();//netpay

       FinalProject output = new FinalProject();


        System.out.print("Good day! To you Sir/ma`am Thanks for helping me our program requires you to input your (basic salary) multiple times in order for us to compute your netpay");
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.print("Thank you Sir Have a Good day.");

           System.out.print("\n");
              System.out.print("\n");
                 System.out.print("\n");
                    System.out.print("\n");
                       System.out.print("\n");


        System.out.print("Enter Employee name: ");
        output1.setName(input.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Enter your basic salary: ");
        output7.setBasicsalary(input.nextDouble());

        System.out.print("Please Enter Your basic salary again to compute the philhealth contribution: ");
        output2.setSalary(input.nextDouble());

        System.out.print("Please Enter your basic salary again to compute the hdmf: ");
        output3.setSalary2(input.nextDouble());

        System.out.print("Please Enter the amount of HDMF you want to share: \n otherwise Enter 0 to deduct the default 100 HDMF share: \n");
        output3.setHdmf(input.nextDouble());

        System.out.print("Please Enter your basic salary again to deduct the SSS in your salary: ");
        output4.setSalary3(input.nextDouble());

        System.out.print("\n\nSSS deduction is: " + output4.getSalary3());
        System.out.print("\n");

        System.out.print("(Please Enter the SSS duduction value above to compute the your tax): ");
        output6.setTax(input.nextDouble());

        System.out.print("Please Enter again your basic salary to compute your netpay: ");
        output8.setNetpay(input.nextDouble());

        System.out.print("Enter your basic salary again to determine your position: ");
        output5.setCout(input.nextDouble());




         System.out.print("Employee name is: " + output1.getName());
         System.out.print("\n");

         System.out.print("Your basic salary is: " + output7.getBasicsalary());
         System.out.print("\n");

         System.out.print("Philhealth contribution is: " + output2.getSalary());
         System.out.print("\n");

         System.out.print("Your HDMF share is: " + output3.getHdmf());
         System.out.print("\n");
         System.out.print("SSS deduction is: " + output4.getSalary3());
         System.out.print("\n");
         System.out.print("Your deduction Tax is: " + output6.getTax());
         System.out.print("\n");
         System.out.print("Your netpay is: " + output8.getNetpay());



    }
}
```

Comment: It is my 1st time posting here and it seems my code is messed up
please see my code in the link below:

 notepad.pw/myjavacode

Comment: Post only the code which is required..

Comment: Welcome to SO! :) Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page(https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Having `8` instances of `FinalProject`...ouch. Having to re-enter your basic salary constantly is not very good design either.

Comment: I `m so sorry i am not yet used in java programming that`s why there are 8intances, and i am sorry again it is my first time posting it seems my code question is apprehend. i am  just wondering if it possible to  use the value of setter to another setter using (this) operator or any kind of method.

Comment: Edit your question, remove any excess code (we're not going to read through it all) and format properly the important part of the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    Please check carefully that, you have initiate multiple "FinalProject" object,
```

do just a single time "FinalProject output = new FinalProject();" at main method

```
    please find code here - 

    /*--------------- FinalProject Class Begin ------------ */
    package teststack;

    public class FinalProject

    {

    //------------------------------- Attributes --------------------------------

    public String name;
    public double cout;
    public int choice;
    public Double temp;
    public Double salary;
    public  Double salary2;
    public  Double salary3;  
    public Double share;
    public Double hdmf;
    public Double sss;
    public Double tax;
    public Double basicsalary;
    public Double netpay;

    //------------------------------- Constructor --------------------------------

    public FinalProject (){

    this.name="";
    this.cout=0.0;
    this.temp=0.0;
    this.choice = 0;
    this.basicsalary = 0.0;
    this.salary=0.0;
    this.salary2=salary;
    this.salary3=0.0;
    this.share=0.0;
    this.hdmf=0.0;
    this.sss=0.0;
    this.tax=0.0;   
    this.netpay = 0.0;
    }  

    //------------------------------- Setter --------------------------------

    public void setName(String name){

    this.name=name;

    }

    public void setCout(Double salary){

    if (salary < 30000.00){
          System.out.print("\n ----------------- \n RESULT:"); 
       System.out.print("\nYour Position is Staff" + "\n");
    }

    else if (salary >= 30000.00 && salary <= 49999.00){
          System.out.print("\n ----------------- \n RESULT:"); 
        System.out.print("\nYour Position is Supervisor"+ "\n");
    }

    else if (salary >= 50000.00 && salary <= 79999.00){
          System.out.print("\n ----------------- \n RESULT:"); 
        System.out.print("\nYour Position is Manager"+ "\n");
    }

     else if (salary >= 80000.00 && salary <= 100000.00){
           System.out.print("\n ----------------- \n RESULT:"); 
        System.out.print("\nYour Position is Junior Officer"+ "\n");
    }

     else if (salary > 100001.00){
           System.out.print("\n ----------------- \n RESULT:"); 
        System.out.print("\nYour Position is Senior Officer"+ "\n");
    }

    // salary = cout;

    }

    public void setChoice(int choice){

    this.choice=choice;

    }

    public void setBasicsalary(Double basicsalary){

    this.basicsalary = basicsalary;

    }

    public void setNetpay(Double netpay){

    netpay = -this.salary - this.hdmf - this.salary3 - this.tax;
            this.netpay=netpay;

    }

    public void setSalary(Double salary){

    if(salary <= 8999.99 )
        {
            salary = 100.00;

        }

    else if(salary >= 9000 && salary <= 9999.99)
    {
        salary = 112.50;

    }

    else if(salary >= 10000 && salary <= 10999.99)
    {
        salary = 125.00;

    }

    else if(salary >= 11000 && salary <= 11999.99)
    {
        salary = 137.50;

    }

    else if(salary >= 12000 && salary <= 12999.99)
    {
        salary = 150.00;

    }

    else if(salary >= 13000 && salary <= 13999.99)
    {
        salary = 162.50;

    }

    else if(salary >= 14000 && salary <= 14999.99)
    {
        salary = 175.50;

    }

    else if(salary >= 15000 && salary <= 15999.99)
    {
        salary = 187.50;

    }

    else if(salary >= 16000 && salary <= 16999.99)
    {
        salary = 200.00;

    }

    else if(salary >= 17000 && salary <= 17999.99)
    {
        salary = 212.50;

    }

    else if(salary >= 18000 && salary <= 18999.99)
    {
        salary = 225.00;

    }

    else if(salary >= 19000 && salary <= 19999.99)
    {
        salary = 237.50;

    }

    else if(salary >= 20000 && salary <= 20999.99)
    {
        salary = 250.00;

    }

    else if(salary >= 21000 && salary <= 21999.99)
    {
        salary = 262.50;

    }

    else if(salary >= 22000 && salary <= 22999.99)
    {
        salary = 275.00;

    }

    else if(salary >= 23000 && salary <= 23999.99)
    {
        salary = 287.50;

    }

    else if(salary >= 24000 && salary <= 24999.99)
    {
        salary = 300.00;

    }

    else if(salary >= 25000 && salary <= 25999.99)
    {
        salary = 312.50;

    }

    else if(salary >= 26000 && salary <= 26999.99)
    {
        salary = 325.00;

    }

    else if(salary >= 27000 && salary <= 27999.99)
    {
        salary = 337.50;

    }

    else if(salary >= 28000 && salary <= 28999.99)
    {
        salary = 350.00;

    }

    else if(salary >= 29000 && salary <= 29999.99)
    {
        salary = 362.50;

    }

    else if(salary >= 30000 && salary <= 30999.99)
    {
        salary = 375.00;

    }

    else if(salary >= 31000 && salary <= 31999.99)
    {
        salary = 387.50;

    }

    else if(salary >= 32000 && salary <= 32999.99)
    {
        salary = 400.00;

    }

    else if(salary >= 33000 && salary <= 33999.99)
    {
        salary = 412.50;

    }

    else if(salary >= 34000 && salary <= 34999.99)
    {
        salary = 425.00;

    }

    else if(salary >= 35000)
    {
        salary = 437.50;

    }

    this.salary=salary;

    } public void setSalary2(Double salary2){

    this.salary2=salary2;

    }

    public void temp(Double temp){

    this.temp=temp;

    }

    public void setSalary3(Double salary3){

     if(this.salary3 < 30000){
       salary3 = salary3 * 0.05;
    }

    else if (this.salary3 >= 30000 && this.salary3 <= 49999){
       salary3 = salary3 * 0.07;
    }

    else if (this.salary3 >= 50000 && this.salary3 <= 79999){
        salary3 = salary3 * 0.08;
    }

     else if (this.salary3 >= 80000 && this.salary3 <= 100000){
         salary3 =salary3 * 0.1;
    }

     else if (this.salary3 > 100001){
        salary3 = salary3 * 0.15;
    }


    this.salary3=salary3;

    }

    public void setShare(Double share){

    this.share=share;

    }

    public void setTemp(Double temp){

    this.temp=temp;

    }

    public void setHdmf(Double hdmf){

    if(hdmf > 100){
            System.out.print("Prefered HDMF value has been entered" + "\n");

              this.hdmf = hdmf;

        }
        else if(hdmf == 0){
            System.out.print("Default has been chosen to deduct 100 HDMF" + "\n");
            salary2 = 100.00;
             this.hdmf = salary2;
        }

    }

    public void setSss(Double sss){

    this.sss = sss * 0.50;   

    }

    public void setTax(Double tax){

    this.tax = tax * 0.50;

    }

    //getter

    public String getName(){

    return this.name;

    }

    public Double getCout(){

    return this.cout;

    }

    public int getChoice(){

    return this.choice;

    }

    public Double getBasicsalary(){

    return this.basicsalary;

    }

    public Double getNetpay(){

    return this.netpay;

    }

    public Double getSalary(){

    return this.salary;

    }

    public Double getTemp(){

    return this.temp;

    }

    public Double getSalary2(){

    return this.salary2;

    }

    public Double getSalary3(){

    return this.salary3;

    }

    public Double getShare(){

    return this.share;

    }

    public Double getHdmf(){

    return this.hdmf;

    }

    public Double getSss(){

    return this.sss;

    }

    public Double getTax(){

    return this.tax;

    }

    }

    /*--------------- FinalProject Class End ------------ */

    /*--------------- FinalProjectMain Class Begin ------------ */

    package teststack;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class FinalProjectMain {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    try{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    FinalProject output = new FinalProject();


    System.out.print("Good day! To you Sir/ma`am Thanks for helping me our program requires you to input your (basic salary) multiple times in order for us to compute your netpay");
    System.out.print("\nThank you Sir Have a Good day.\n\n\n");
    System.out.print("Enter Employee name: ");
    output.setName(input.nextLine());

    System.out.print("Enter your basic salary: ");
    output.setBasicsalary(input.nextDouble());

    System.out.print("Please Enter Your basic salary again to compute the philhealth contribution: ");
    output.setSalary(input.nextDouble());

    System.out.print("Please Enter your basic salary again to compute the hdmf: ");
    output.setSalary2(input.nextDouble());

    System.out.print("Please Enter the amount of HDMF you want to share: \n otherwise Enter 0 to deduct the default 100 HDMF share: \n");
    output.setHdmf(input.nextDouble());

    System.out.print("Please Enter your basic salary again to deduct the SSS in your salary: ");
    output.setSalary3(input.nextDouble());

    System.out.print("\n\nSSS deduction is: " + output.getSalary3());
    System.out.print("\n");

    System.out.print("(Please Enter the SSS duduction value above to compute the your tax): ");
    output.setTax(input.nextDouble());

    System.out.print("Please Enter again your basic salary to compute your netpay: ");
    output.setNetpay(input.nextDouble());

    System.out.print("Enter your basic salary again to determine your position: ");
    output.setCout(input.nextDouble());

     System.out.print("Employee name is: " + output.getName());
     System.out.print("\n");

     System.out.print("Your basic salary is: " + output.getBasicsalary());
     System.out.print("\n");

     System.out.print("Philhealth contribution is: " + output.getSalary());
     System.out.print("\n");

     System.out.print("Your HDMF share is: " + output.getHdmf());
     System.out.print("\n");
     System.out.print("SSS deduction is: " + output.getSalary3());
     System.out.print("\n");
     System.out.print("Your deduction Tax is: " + output.getTax());
     System.out.print("\n");
     System.out.print("Your netpay is: " + output.getNetpay());
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("ex : "+e);
    }


}

}

    /*--------------- FinalProjectMain Class End ------------ */
```